# Si se esta escribiendo en un Edit Text haz esto

Tags: java, android-studio, edittext

Actualmente estoy buscando si hay alguna función para el `EditText` que detecte si estas sobre el haga alguna acción.

```
if(et_actualiza.getText().equals("")){
        AutoCompletarCerca.agafarNoms(groups,Productes,ArrayNom,ArrayFormulat,ArrayNumRegistre,ArrayTitular);
        btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if(!et_actualiza.getText().equals("")){
        btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Intente probar-lo así pero no va.
El objetivo es que desaparezca el botón al escribir un caracter o simplemente al hacer click sobre el `EditText`.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se puede conseguir con TextWacther, te dejo el link de un ejemplo, pero está en inglés.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener
Espero que te sirva. :D

Comment: Aqui te dejo la documentación del TextWacther pero también está en inglés jeje
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher). Asociando este tipo de objeto a un Editable (tu EditText), hará que sus métodos se ejecuten cuando se modifique el texto:

```
et_actualiza.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
            if(!s.equals("") ) { 
                //Aquí se trabaja cuando se edita el texto del EditText. 
            }
    }



    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Esto es lo que yo te decía pero aplicado a tu caso. Te doy +1 Mario L, :D.

Comment: es raro porque añado este código `if (s.equals("")){
                    btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if(!s.equals("")){
                    btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{

                }` y el botón aparece una vez y cuando borro lo que hay dentro ya no hace nada. Se queda siempre visible.

Comment: Si el EditText no contiene nada (s.equals("")) se oculta el botón, si no, se muestra: if(s.equals("")){btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.GONE);}else{btn_cerca2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}